# How to resolve server related error when testing multiple TypeScript APIs?

Tags: typescript, testing, web-api-testing

I would like to test the POST and GET methods of two APIs called `Restaurant` and `Employee`. The two APIs work as expected. This question is specifically about how to test the two APIs? I have created 2 test files that I have included below. For orginization purposes, I have put them in 2 separate directories `test\restaurant\index.test.ts` and `test\employee\index.test.ts`. When I run the tests individually the test file executes and all tests pass. It seems that when I run the following script `npm run knex:latest && npm run test:compile && npm run test:script` not all tests work. In particular, that script is supposed to execute all test files. But when I run it not all tests pass. Is there a different way I should setting up these test files so that I can keep the files organized in this way but all tests run without the server not having started?

`test\restaurant\index.test.ts`

```
import { before, describe, it, after } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'node:assert';
import { promisify } from 'node:util';
import { Server } from 'http';

describe('Restaurant Test Suite', () => {
  let serverTest: Server;
  before(async () => {
    const { server } = await import('../../src/index');
    serverTest = server;
  });
  after(async () => {
    try {
      await promisify(serverTest.close.bind(serverTest))();
      return process.exit(0);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return process.exit(1);
    }
  });
  it('Restaurant Post', async (t) => {
    const testPort = process.env.PORT;

    const testServerAddress = `http://localhost:${testPort}/api/v1/restaurant`;

    await t.test('it should create a restaurant', async () => {
      const data = {
        name: 'Test Name',
        active: false,
        description: 'Test Description',
      };
      const request = await fetch(testServerAddress, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });

      assert.strictEqual(request.status, 200);
      interface Result {
        message: string;
      }
      const result = await (<Promise<Result>>request.json());
      assert.deepStrictEqual(
        result.message,
        'Restaurant created successfully',
        'it should return a valid text message',
      );
    });
  });
  it('Get Restaurants', async (t) => {
    const testPort = process.env.PORT;

    const testServerAddress = `http://localhost:${testPort}/api/v1/restaurants`;

    await t.test('it should get restaurants', async () => {
      const request = await fetch(testServerAddress, {
        method: 'GET',
      });

      assert.strictEqual(request.status, 200);
      interface Data {
        id: string;
      }
      interface Result {
        data: Array<Data>;
      }
      const result = await (<Promise<Result>>request.json());
      console.log(result);
      assert.ok(result.data[0].id.length > 30, 'Restaurant uuid successfully');
    });
  });
});
```

`test\employee\index.test.ts`

```
import { before, describe, it, after } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'node:assert';
import { promisify } from 'node:util';
import { Server } from 'http';

describe('Employee Test Suite', () => {
  let serverTest: Server;
  before(async () => {
    const { server } = await import('../../src/index');
    serverTest = server;
  });
  after(async () => {
    try {
      await promisify(serverTest.close.bind(serverTest))();
      return process.exit(0);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return process.exit(1);
    }
  });
  it('Employee Post', async (t) => {
    const testPort = process.env.PORT;

    // https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/test.html#mocking
    const testServerAddress = `http://localhost:${testPort}/api/v1/employee`;

    await t.test('it should create a employee', async () => {
      const data = {
        name: 'Test Employee Name',
        employee_availability: []
      };
      const request = await fetch(testServerAddress, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });

      assert.strictEqual(request.status, 200);
      interface Result {
        message: string;
      }
      const result = await (<Promise<Result>>request.json());
      assert.deepStrictEqual(
        result.message,
        'Employee created successfully',
        'it should return a valid text message',
      );
    });
  });
  it('Get Employees', async (t) => {
    const testPort = process.env.PORT;

    const testServerAddress = `http://localhost:${testPort}/api/v1/offerings`;

    await t.test('it should get employees', async () => {
      const request = await fetch(testServerAddress, {
        method: 'GET',
      });

      assert.strictEqual(request.status, 200);
      interface Data {
        id: string;
      }
      interface Result {
        data: Array<Data>;
      }
      const result = await (<Promise<Result>>request.json());
      console.log(result);
      assert.ok(result.data[0].id.length > 30, 'Employee uuid successfully');
    });
  });
});
```

ERROR LOG:

```
# (node:128) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
# (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
# Subtest: Offering Test Suite
# Error [ERR_SERVER_NOT_RUNNING]: Server is not running.
#     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
#     at Server.close (node:net:2161:12)
#     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:631:28)
#     at Server.emit (node:events:517:28)
#     at emitCloseNT (node:net:2221:8)
#     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
#   code: 'ERR_SERVER_NOT_RUNNING'
# }
# Subtest: /app/test/employee/index.test.js
not ok 2 - /app/test/employee/index.test.js
```

Any assistance on how to test these two APIs without the server going down halfway through would be much appreciated! Maybe there's something I've missed that I'm unaware of.

Comment: `return process.exit(0);` why are you tearing everything down after your test?

Comment: The thought was to exit everything once the test was completed. Should this be set up differently?